# What's the meaning of this code ///memberpage.php?action=admin_mail_list&type=outbox///

Tags: php

I want to know how this code is working:

```
memberpage.php?action=admin_mail_list&type=outbox
```

Yes, `memberpage.php` is a page but is `admin_mail_list&type=outbox` a separate page?

If No, what is it then?

If Yes, why is there no file type after the name (I mean `.php` or `.html`)?

Comment: Read the manuals on php.net

Comment: See http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing two different parts of a URI. This isn't exclusive to PHP, the URI recommendation applies to all websites regardless of their programming language.

The first (`memberpage.php`) is the *path*, and [W3 describes](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html) it like this:

> **Path**
>
> The rest of the URI follows the colon in a format depending on the
>   scheme. The path is interpreted in a manner dependent on the protocol
>   being used. However, when it contains slashes, these must imply a
>   hierarchical structure.

and the second (`?admin_mail_list&type=outbox`) is the *query string* and is described like this:

> **Query strings**
>
> The question mark ("?", ASCII 3F hex) is used to delimit the boundary
>   between the URI of a queryable object, and a set of words used to
>   express a query on that object. When this form is used, the combined
>   URI stands for the object which results from the query being applied
>   to the original object.
>
> Within the query string, the plus sign is
>   reserved as shorthand notation for a space. Therefore, real plus signs
>   must be encoded. This method was used to make query URIs easier to
>   pass in systems which did not allow spaces.
>
> The query string represents some operation applied to the object, but
>   this specification gives no common syntax or semantics for it. In
>   practice the syntax and sematics may depend on the scheme and may even
>   on the base URI.

To put it simply, the *path* of the URI dictates which script is to be run, and fields in the query string are *parameters* to use in that script.

If you're familiar with working on the command line it might be easier to think of these parameters like **options** on a command line utility.  A comparable command might look something like this:

```
$ php memberpage.php --admin_mail_list --type=outbox
```

It's important to remember that parameters like this **aren't** necessarily required to access the URI so it's inappropriate to think of these are *arguments* on a command line. If your script absolutely needs these parameters to function, you must create that logic within the script yourself, as it is not enforced by the URI.

---

To answer your question directly:

**Yes!**

Passing different parameters to the URI can lead to *wildly* different pages.You absolutely should consider different URI's to be different pages because from the perspective of your users and the larger web, they certainly are.  Both users and search engines will consider them distinct and so should you.

Answer (score 2):

That link is using the `GET` method, meaning variables are defined in the **URL** rather than the **PHP** code itself.

For example, if you were to run a Google or Bing search, it wouldn't just be:

`https://google.com/search`

It would be something like:

`https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=test`

The benefit of using this, is if the page is refreshed or sent to a friend, the variable won't need to be redefined like **POST**, it's already *defined* in the URL.

So, for example, you may have :

`http://example.com/example?q=test`

The `/example` page would have this PHP code:

`echo $_GET['q'];`

which would print "test".

See the following pages if you need more help.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Answer (score 1):

That means that the "memberpage.php" script takes two parameters via $_GET:

- "action" which has the value "admin_mail_list"
- "type" which has the value "outbox"

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php